# How to install Apache2::Ajax for windows without ppm

Tags: ajax, windows, perl, mod-perl

Does anyone know how to install perl's Apache2::Ajax on windows when there isn't a ppm? I have perl5.10. I can download the source tar file but can't use the makefile.pl or build.pl in it to build Apache2::Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have ActivePerl. You will need to install mod_perl first, there are additional repositories you can enable in ppm manager options. Then run "cpan Apache2::Ajax" from command line.

Comment: I have mod_perl installed. As you suggested I ran "cpan Apache2::Ajax". I got the following errors:<br>Argument "6.42_01" isn't numeric in numeric ge (>=) at Makefile.PL line 20, where 6.42_01 is the $ExtUtils::MakeMaker::VERSION.<br>I also got the following error:<br>Cannot opendir C:\Apache2.2\lib: No such file or directory at D:\Perl\Perl5_10\site\lib/Apache2/Build.pm line 1664.<br>For some reason the build thinks my Apache2.2 is at C:\Apache2.2 which it isn't.<br>And, of course the test on the end didn't work.

Comment: Search for location of "C:\Apache2.2" in D:\Perl\Perl5_10\site\lib/Apache2/ . It is possible that this information is stored inside Apache2::BuildConfig. Replace it with correct path.

Comment: BuildConfig.pm seems to be some of the problem. The paths in it for Apache2 are all wrong. Plus, it expects there to be "lib" folder in the apache root which older versions of apache have. But, version I have doesn't (I installed my version about a month ago. So, it is relatively new.)